# Calling (deleteRowsAtIndexPaths) outside of (commitEditingStyle) in Objective-C for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has two custom `UIButton`'s added to it. On one of these buttons I want to be able to delete the cell row from within `myMethod()`.

The method is called by `addTarget:@selector(myMethod:)` within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    cell.acceptButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:acceptButton];

    [cell.acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

This works, the actual method is called successfully.

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)sender {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; //works fine (correct indexPath is returned)
   friendsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //works fine (correct indexPath.row is returned and the object is removed from the array)
   [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; //throws error below
}
```

Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x020a9be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x021fe5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ff3ffe -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 494
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x020158a3 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 67
 4   MyApp                          0x00071d1b -[FriendListViewController myMethod:] + 417
 5   MyApp                          0x00020b87 -[MBProgressHUD launchExecution] + 151
 6   Foundation                          0x004a3d4c -[NSThread main] + 81
 7   Foundation                          0x004a3cd8 __NSThread__main__ + 1387
 8   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9461f85d _pthread_start + 345
 9   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9461f6e2 thread_start + 34
```

Normally I would do this when deleting a row within a cell. This works fine:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
  //Delete the object from the friends array and the table.
  [friendsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
}
```

Comment: mind adding the solution? I just encountered a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a uibutton on every cell or more than one cell and setting a same selector than the best option to find out the cell is by using tags.

i did this when i want to change the color of my accessory buttons to green (i dont know if apple will allow this or not but just something i want to try). so made a custom button and changed its background image to green and then in the accessoryView i added that button. And it worked just fine. You need to set the tag in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: I actually found what the problem is. If the actual row is not selected then the same line throws an error. If it IS selected then it works just fine. So is there another way of deleting the row without it actually being selected?

Comment: @robin: indexPath is a NSIndexPath object, not the row number. @Fulvio: If you want to delete a non-selected row, then you have to already know what the index path of the cell is. UITableView has methods for getting the index path of a cell given the cell object or a point on the screen within the cell.

Comment: I have set the tags for the buttons to the indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath. However the tag is always returning 0 even if I select the second row in the list.

Comment: @robin I edited my original question with the code I'm using to tag the button in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @robin Woohoo! I figured out the issue. I was setting the tag on an ivar incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in array initialization, not row deletion. Try to debug this method one more time and check if indexPath could be nil.

Comment: It's not nil and the array is initialised properly.

Comment: @Fulvio: well, runtime disagrees with you: '*** -[NSArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]'

Comment: The problem IS in commitEditingStyle method because it crashes INSIDE iOS libs.